# Improving running time for a scheduling algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

Suppose a switch takes `a` minutes switch on a light and it is on for `b` minutes. The aim is to have the lights on in at least 1 minute and print the order of lights to turn on, else it should print `-1`.

Suppose I have an input as follows:

```
2
1 5
5 10
```

- The first line is 1 <= n <= 10^4 of how many switches there are.
- The second line is how much time it takes for each switches to turn
  on.
- The third line is how long the light stays on.

So one switch: a=1, b=5 and the other switch: a=5, b=10

If we turned on switch 1 then 2, it would look something like this:

> ```
> let turn on time: 0
> let on time: 1
>
> 011111
>  0000011111
> ```

And we won't be able to satisfy the condition. If on the other hand we have 2 then 1, it will be

> ```
> 0000011111
>      011111
> ```

So the light turns on for 4 minutes > 1 so that's good, and the output is

> ```
> 2 1
> ```

Other inputs:

> ```
> 2
> 5 5
> 5 5
> ```

Output: `-1` (since the turn on time is the same as the other's on time)

> ```
> 3
> 1 4 1
> 5 3 4
> ```

Output: `2 1 3` or `2 3 1`

My code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Switch {
public:
  int num;
  int turnon;
  int time;

  Switch(int n) { num = n; turnon = 0; time = 0; }
};

bool comparator(Switch a, Switch b) { return a.turnon > b.turnon; }

int main()
{
  int n=0;
  cin >> n;

  vector<Switch> v;
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    Switch s = Switch(i+1);
    v.push_back(s);
  }

  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    int a = 0;
    cin >> a;
    v[i].turnon = a;
  }

  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    int b = 0;
    cin >> b;
    v[i].time = b;
  }

  while(v.size() >= 1) {
    int maxtimeleft = -2147484637;
    int maxindex = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
      int time = v[i].time;
      for(int j=0; j<v.size(); j++) {
        if(j!=i)
          time -= v[j].turnon;
      }
      if(time > maxtimeleft) {
        maxtimeleft = time;
        maxindex = i;
      }     
    }
    if(maxtimeleft < 1) {
        cout << "-1";
        return 0;
    }
    cout << v[maxindex].num << endl;
    v.erase(v.begin()+maxindex);
  }
```

**Main idea: I go through each switch then subtract all the other switch's 'turn on time' from its 'on time'. And I find the switch that gives me the greatest time left, then print it out and remove it, then this repeats until there is only 1 switch left.**

This code passes the first three tests but fails a test that said "Time Limit Error". I suppose this is because this algorithm is a O(n^3) algorithm since it has two `for` loops looking for the best switch to remove and it repeats it until there are no more switches left. Any idea on how to improve this? This is a homework problem.

Comment: How many programmers does it take to take to turn on  a light? … Really, please do some background research and mention what canonical algorithm or problem this is really about.

Comment: I have no idea to be honest. This is somewhat a sorting problem but I don't know any well known programming challenges like this.

Comment: It looks a lot like a scheduling problem. The zany light-switch metaphor makes the question look a lot like homework. It certainly doesn't look like anything to do with real-world light switches, so in StackOverflow terms it's at best an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: This really isn't a C++ question. You're better off first figuring out your algorithm using pencil and paper, and only writing any code at all when you're done with the first step.

Comment: … If it *is* a homework problem, refer to the slides for the previous lecture to orient yourself (and us) what general part of CS we are in!

Comment: I will update the question to reflect the type of problem, I did spend a disproportionate amount of time on this already, so I really don't know what I'm doing wrong and just need some hints.

Comment: Clarification: is the objective to have all lights simultaneously ON for at least 1 minute?

Comment: I didn't look at the algorithm, but a glaring issue is the unnecessary iteration in your inner loop where you substract `v[j].turnon` from `time` for all `j` that isn't `i`; just sum up all `turnon` times for switches in the vector (once per outermost loop), and then subtract `sum_turnon - v[i].turnon` instead. This would bring the code to `O(N^2)`.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis yes.

Comment: @T.C. This actually ended up solving my problem! Thanks! I calculated all the `turnon` times first so that I don't have an n^2 algorithm but 2n = O(n) instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest solution I can think of is:

1. Calculate the total amount of time (T) it takes to switch on all lights.
2. For each switch calculate the earliest point in time t_i you can switch it on, such that the light still burns at T+1.
3. Sort the switches according to that criteria.

The asymtotic complexity is dominated by the sort, so you will end up with O(n (log (n))).

Depending on how large the numbers get, you can trade space for time and turn this into an algorithm of armortized linear complexity (with possibly high constants) by allocating a vector with one element for each minute and directly place each switch at position t_i in that vector. Essentially you are creating a very sparse hash table.

Finally, you could adjust the granularity in a dynamic manner, but unless you have very stringent time and space constraints I dont think that would be necessary.